# Is there a way in NiFi to route data based on filed name?

Tags: routes, apache-nifi

Let's say we have a Csv file in which I have 5 fields as Id, Age, FirstName, LastName,Address.

I want to route all the numeric field( Id, Age) in one flow and string fields(FirstName,LastName,Address) in other flow. I am using GetFile processor to get all the CSV.

Which processor to use and what config to set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. It can easily be done, if you are well aware of what are all the fields before hand. If that's the case, you can use `QueryRecord` processor to separate the content of the FlowFiles based on the fields into different FlowFiles.

[image]

`QueryRecord` takes dynamic relationships which takes a SQL statement as the value. For example, assume you have the following content in your CSV.

```
id,name,age,gender
1,John,29,M
5,Janine,31,F
```

And you want to have `id` and `age` in a FlowFile and `name` and `gender` in a another FlowFile, you need to configure `QueryRecord` as below:

[image]

Since `QueryRecord` is a record based processor, you want to configure a RecordReader and RecordWriter (I have used `CSVReader` / `CSVRecordSetWriter` since our input and output is going to be CSV) and may need to configure them with a `SchemaRegistry`

**Output - numeric fields**

[image]

**Output - non numeric fields**

[image]

**Hint**: In case you're going to use `AvroSchemaRegistry`, you can use `InferAvroSchema` processor to infer the Avro schema for you CSV input.